# Phonegap geolocation PERMISSION_DENIED

Tags: javascript, cordova, geolocation

I am about to create an app using PhoneGap. But I have a problem with geolocation. Error code is "PERMISSION_DENIED" even though I have location services enabled for the app.

I have noticed two things. 
Geolocation works when I run the app in hydration mode. 
The app crashes when I visit the map where I use geolocation. Goes back and then to the map again.

iPhone 5s IOS8
org.apache.cordova.geolocation 0.3.10 
Phonegap 3.5

```
// Code for Map page
if (page.name === 'map') {
    var latitude = page.query.latitude;
    var longitude = page.query.longitude;

    function success(position) {
        var latitude = page.query.latitude;
        var longitude = page.query.longitude;

        var mapcanvas = document.createElement('div');
        mapcanvas.id = 'mapcontainer';
        mapcanvas.style.height = '100%';
        mapcanvas.style.width = '100%';

        document.getElementById('map-wrap').appendChild(mapcanvas);

        var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
        var malet = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        var options = {
            zoom: 10,
            center: coords,
            mapTypeControl: false,
            navigationControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
            },
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapcontainer"), options);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: malet,
            map: map
        });

        var address = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            $$.getJSON('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=' + latitude + ',' + longitude + '&sensor=true', function(json) {
                address.setContent(json.results[0].formatted_address);
            });
            address.open(map, marker);
        });

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            map: map,
            position: coords,
            content: 'Här är du!'
        });

        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        bounds.extend(malet);
        bounds.extend(coords);
        map.fitBounds(bounds)

    }

    // onError Callback receives a PositionError object
    function onError(error) {
        switch (error.code) {
            case 1:
                myApp.alert("Du måste aktivera platstjänser för BAPPen.");
                break;
            case 2:
                myApp.alert("Din position kunde inte fastställas.");
                break;
            case 3:
                myApp.alert("The request to get user location timed out.");
                break;
            case 4:
                myApp.alert("An unknown error occurred.");
                break;
        }

    }
    var options = {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        timeout: 5000,
        maximumAge: 0
    };


    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, onError, options);
    } else {
        error('Geo Location is not supported');
    }

}
```

Comment: The issue may be with the path of `config.xml`. Is it as part of the upload? Take a look at http://thejackalofjavascript.com/framework7-phonegap-getting-started/#comment-1676196881

Comment: I find geolocation inside the plugin list, but it still does not work. @Arvind

Answer (score 0):

Verify that your phone's GPS is on and that it is enabled in your config.xml file.  That's generally the source of PERMISSION_DENIED.

Look at http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html - (in app/res/xml/config.xml)

```
<feature name="Geolocation">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.geolocation.GeoBroker" />
</feature>
```

(in app/AndroidManifest.xml)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Also, the error you're getting is addressed there as well:

```
PositionError.PERMISSION_DENIED: Returned when users do not allow the app to retrieve position information. This is dependent on the platform.
```

Comment: How do I activate the GPS in config.xml? 
I've Cordova geolocation installed in the config file. @wbt11a

Comment: I tried to add the code for iOS but it did not really. @wbt11a

Comment: I think so anyway, if you mean that the app is the folder where my files are located. @wbt11a